# stop adobe acrobat submit form action from opening a blank pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, adobe, acrobat

i have a pdf form with a submit button. in the submit button, i set it to have submit form action. And the settings is HTML and the URL to a .net page to process the pdf. Everything is working fine except that when it's done, it open a blank pdf on top of the current pdf that i just click the submit button. Is there away to do just a popup or something to say form has been submitted? Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to do some evaluation server-side to find out whether the data has been submitted by Acrobat/Reader.

If so, you could return a PDF of a receipt page, which could be static or dynamic. Dynamically created, you could provide a real receipt with timestamp and maybe even some relevant submitted data.

Keep in mind that Acrobat can interpret HTML answers, but Reader can not. Reader can only deal with PDF and FDF.

Using FDF, you could trigger a status message by an accordingly assembled FDF (I have seen this somewhere in the documentation, but can't remember where).